# error in websphere8.5.5.7 when trying to deploy spring war file with java1.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websphere-8

Can anyone please help me on the following error:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[mvc-dispatcher]: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Trying to instanciate interface javax.persistence.ColumnResult with unknown elements    
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)    
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)     
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)  
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)    
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)  
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)  
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)  
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)  
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)     
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)  
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)  
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)    
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)  
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)   
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)   
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:344)     
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)     
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:636)    
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:480)    
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)    
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1114)  
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3926)    
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)     
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1007)   
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1817)   
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)  
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:463)  
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:530)  
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:316)    
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:287)     
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)     
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)     
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)    
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)    
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)   
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)  
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)    
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1881) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Trying to instanciate interface javax.persistence.ColumnResult with unknown elements  
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.annotationfactory.AnnotationProxy.getAnnotationValues(AnnotationProxy.java:88)  
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.annotationfactory.AnnotationProxy.<init>(AnnotationProxy.java:69)   
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.annotationfactory.AnnotationFactory.create(AnnotationFactory.java:47)   
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.buildColumnResult(JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.java:2182)    
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.buildConstructorResult(JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.java:2193)   
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.buildSqlResultsetMappings(JPAOverriddenAnnotationReader.java:2081)    
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.reflection.JPAMetadataProvider.getDefaults(JPAMetadataProvider.java:154)   
    at org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.getDefaults(JavaReflectionManager.java:252)   
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1388)   
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)     
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)  
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)  
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)   
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)  
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)    
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:67)     
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)     
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)   
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)     
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Add your `spring-config.xml` file, something is wrong with `EntityManagerFactory` bean definition..

Comment: spring-config.xml file already exists in WEB-INF folder and I am connecting websphere datasource... code snippet below <bean id="irrsDatasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/rehab" />
  <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="irrsDatasource" />

Comment: My appln works well in tomcat server locally but when I am trying to deploy in websphere8.5.5.7 which is in remote throws me this error.. somebody pls help me as soon as possible ,i am struck from 2 days and i'm new to websphere ..